# Final logical value of boolean array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, boolean, boolean-logic

Lets say I have an array that looks like:

```
[true, true, false]
```

And I am passing an operator along with the array which may be `AND`, `OR` or `XOR`.

So I want to calculate the logical value of array based on the operator specified.

ex:

for the given array `[true, true, false]` and the operator `AND`
I should be able to perform in continuation for n number of elements in array

```
Steps: true AND true -> true, true AND false -> false
```

therefore the output should be `false`

the array can be an n number of boolean values.

Answer (score 3):

The best and easiest way to do this is using `reduce`:

```
def logical_calculation(arr, op)
  op=='AND' ? arr.reduce(:&) : op=='OR' ? arr.reduce(:|) : arr.reduce(:^)
end
```

and also the other way is might be using `inject`

```
OPS = { "AND" => :&, "OR" => :|, "XOR" => :^ }

    def logical_calculation(array, op)
      array.inject(&OPS[op])
    end
```

Comment: IIRC, `inject` and `reduce` is just an aliast to the same function. Try out yourself, both examples should be working exactly the same if you swap function names

Comment: The ternary method is  absurd and should be removed. The version with the look-up table should be the only answer here.

Comment: `inject`/`reduce` is like `map`/`select` and `length`/`size`, they're just aliases.

Comment: You asked a question you were clearly already, or became relatively immediately, aware of the answer to and answered it yourself? Can you explain your reasoning? Additionally the first as @tadman stated is "absurd" and secondly assumes not "AND" or "OR" is "XOR" and the second will raise for any value not "AND", "OR" or "XOR". And in both cases these are not logical operations but rather bitwise (binary)operations. logical AND is `&&` and logical OR is  `||`  (`and` and `or` are also technically logical but due to precedence are usually referred to as control flow operators).

Comment: Additionally this assumes `array[0]` is always a `TrueClass` or `FalseClass` otherwise errors abound